# symfony doctrine error on flush

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, symfony

I have a SecurityController with a resetPasswordAction like this:

```
  /**
   * @Route("/reset-password", name="security.resetPassword")
   */
  public function resetPasswordAction(Request $request) {

    if (!$request->isMethod('POST')) {
      return $this->render('security/reset-password.html.twig');
    }

    $em =$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $email = $request->request->get('_email');
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === FALSE) {
      $this->addFlash(
        'danger',
        sprintf('<strong>%s</strong> is not a valid email address', $email)
      );
      return $this->render('security/reset-password.html.twig');
    }
    $userRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User');

    /**
     * @var $user User
     */
    $user = $userRepository->findOneBy(['email' => $email]);

    if (NULL == $user) {
      $this->addFlash('danger', 'No user found...');
      return $this->redirectToRoute('security.login');
    }

    $token = base64_encode(random_bytes(20));

    $user->setConfirmationToken($token);
    $user->setPasswordRequestedAt();
    $em->flush();
    $this->addFlash('success', 'You got mail...');
    return $this->redirectToRoute('security.login');
  }
```

My problem is that I get this error on `$em->flush`:

```
Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty
```

The stack trace shows this error:

```
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: "Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty" at /Users/foobar/Sites/dev/crm/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php line 189
```

I get the same error when I build a service for this with injected EntityManager and UserRepository.

I can't figure out why there is this error.

Maybe anyone has a suggestion how I can fix this problem?

--->Update

My User Class looks like  (without methods):

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;


use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="Email already taken")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="username", message="Username already taken")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable {
  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
  private $id;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
   * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please provide a username")
   */
  private $username;

  /**
   * @Assert\NotBlank()
   * @Assert\Length(max=4096)
   */
  private $plainPassword;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
   */
  private $password;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, unique=true)
   * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please provide a email")
   */
  private $email;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
   */
  private $roles;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
   */
  private $isActive;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=True)
   */
  private $confirmationToken;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=True)
   */
  private $passwordRequestedAt;
```

Comment: Can you highlight the line where you get the error?

Comment: The error only comes on `$em->flush()`

Comment: You know, the error message has a "line" and a "file" that are quite useful.

Comment: let's see how you've mapped `User`

Comment: I updated the question with the user class

Comment: what's the output of `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); $meta = $em->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata(); var_dump($meta);` ?

Comment: an array with object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata) in it

Comment: maybe irrelevant but shouldn't you try to persist the user before flushing.

Comment: on entity update you don't have to persist @SebastianGreen